# CSS won't affect the Div ID

Tags: css, html

EDITED: I am showing the whole code instead
I know this is probably a really simple question, but I am somewhat new at HTML5 and CSS coding. The problem I am encountering is that I have one line of text I wish to edit individually from the other paragraphs, so I am using a Div ID. The problem is, CSS is linked right to text, but when I add CSS to the div, it won't edit. It's all on a separate sheet, and CSS works for everything else besides the Div. Here is the HTML and CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
        <title>Codetopia - Learn to Code</title>
        <link href="externalfile:drive-be6fc3227f0f52098e01c434b3f53296322df648/root/Coding/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lemonada" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><i>CODETOPIA</i></h1>
        <h1>Learn to Code the <i>Fun</i> Way</h1>
    <a href="google.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.rouzell.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/html_css.png" alt="HTML 5 and CSS3 Image"/></a>
    <p>Explore the world of code through this interective course for ages 7-12.</p>
    <p></p>
    <a href=" " target="_blank"></a>
        <h2>Why Codetopia?</h2>
        <p>Codetopia presents a playful, fun, academic atmosphere for young children to discover. <br /> Here are some of the benefits:</p>
         <ul>
             <li><b><i>100% free</b></i> for everyone at any age</li>
          <li>Learn through an interactive storyline</li>
          <li>Simple to follow steps</li>
          <li>Color-coded text</li>
         </ul>
        <img src="https://edsurge.imgix.net/uploads/post/image/7747/Kids_coding-1456433921.jpg" alt="Coding for Kids"/>
<!--<img src="http://codeteachers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/kids-coding.png
" alt="Coding for Kids"/> is optional image-->
    <h2>How it works</h2>
     <p>The teaching process is extremely unique and flexible. Children start with being introduced to a fictional story, that they can read. Throughout the story, certain issues or missions will be needed where the child then will be taught the basis of coding to help the characters. <br /> Here is more in detail:</p>
         <ol>
          <li>Follow Lee and Madison's numerous interactive adventures</li>
          <li>Learn and develop basic coding skills to help the twins throughout the story</li>
          <li>Put your skills to the test to complete each mission and story</li>
             <div id="join">
             <p><b>Join the Codetopia Adventure today!</b></p>
        </div>
             <!-- Pic of the twins here? Make sure to resize it -->
         </ol>
    </body>
</html>



         * {
  font-family: Georgia,Times,serif;
  background-color: White;
}
h1 {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 42px;
  color: rgba(46,139,87,0.9);
  font-family:'Lemonada',cursive;
  line-height: 1em;
}
h2 {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: SeaGreen;
    color: White;
    margin-right: 1100px;
    font-style:italic;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'Lemonada',cursive;
}
p, li {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
li {
    color: rgb(37,232,98);
#join p {
    color: SeaGreen;
}
```

Comment: Assuming your CSS has a closing `}`, this code works fine. Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: As it's an ID, make sure that the id "join" only appears once in the file. It works perfectly in the code snippet you gave us.

Comment: Your example is a working example. The problem must be with your actual code, which we cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

```
#join p b {
   color: SeaGreen!important;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not helpful. Please explain how your code solves OP's problem. It seems especially important here, to distinguish your answer from all of the other very similar answers which seem to be attracting downvotes. What are they doing wrong that you do right?

Answer (score -1):

as you can see in the doc you are giving color to that DIV not giving color to the child p or b tag of parent div which is based on identifier so how you can gave separate color to text based on ID:

```css
#join p {
    color: SeaGreen;
  }
```

```html
<div id="join">
         <p><b>Join the Codetopia Adventure today!</b></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Okay, so I tried giving the color to the child p tag as you showed, but it is still not working.

Answer (score -1):

you must assign the code to "p" such as this:

```
    #join p{
    color: red !important;
    }
```

in your css you missing one "}" before #join, and the second problem is that SeaGreen is not acceptable, so i change it to red.

Answer (score -1):

if you want your child elements to herit their parents attributes, use !important.

```html
b, p
{
  color: inherit !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To expand on these answers, the reason why you need to specify `#join p` is that CSS rules "cascade" by specificity. I assume you have another style rule for `p` which is considered more specific. 
Another option would be to change your `p` color rule to a `body` color rule.